# How to get chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener() to fire at Chrome startup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on an extension for Chrome that utilizes a native messaging host.  My background.js registers a listener immediately to process all onBeforeRequest events (i.e., all requests) and pass them on to the native helper application.  This is all well and good when a page is visited after Chrome has started up, but when I click a URL that launches Chrome, my listener does not fire.

Here is the basic structure of the listener at the top of my background.js:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    alert('forwarding request!');
    chrome.runtime.sendNativeMessage('<extension name>', { url: details.url });
}, { urls: ['http://*', 'https://*'] }, ['blocking']);
```

Obviously, there are conditions in place that determine whether to pass off the request and block it in Chrome, but they are not relevant here.  Even without the sendNativeMessage bit, I cannot produce an alert for the URL that is clicked to launch an instance of Chrome.

Any clever ways to register this listener before the first request at startup goes through?

Comment: I've noticed that this is a bit of a race condition.  The alert does fire maybe once in every 4-5 startup attempts.  Still hoping that there's a way around it.  I'll really appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: What is "url that launches Chrome"?

Comment: I doubt it's relevant, but this is a ClickOnce extension that simply does MIME Type detection and blocks + hands off `application/x-ms-application` and `application/x-ms-vsto` URLs to a helper application.  Since posting this, we've just been running with background permission, which works well, even if it's not ideal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try giving your extension the `background` [permission](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions):

> Makes Chrome start up early and and shut down late, so that apps and extensions can have a longer life.
>
> When any installed hosted app, packaged app, or extension has "background" permission, Chrome runs (invisibly) as soon as the user logs into their computer—before the user launches Chrome. The "background" permission also makes Chrome continue running (even after its last window is closed) until the user explicitly quits Chrome.

This way the Chrome process and extensions will be loaded before you click any URL. The user can still circumvent this by explicitly killing the Chrome process.

As a side note, keep in mind that the response from your `onBeforeRequest` listener needs to be synchronous if you want to block a request, so you can't base the decision to block on the response from a native messaging host.

Comment: I re-read the question carefully and I think your side note, while valid, does not apply: the code (that OP omits) decides whether to allow the request or block _and_ report it to the Native Host.

Comment: This sounds promising, but the docs seem unclear about whether having a "background" extension enabled keeps Chrome running all the time.  "Start up early and shut down late" seems to indicate that the process will not hang around forever (I would prefer if it didn't).  I will give this a try and see whether the benefits outweigh the costs.  I don't suppose extensions can selectively enable or disable permissions via user-modifiable extension settings.  Thanks!  This looks like the best option at this point.

Comment: @OsbourneRuddock The actual answer is "While user is logged in, unless they disabled 'Let Google Chrome run in the background' or manually closed Chrome from systray icon".

Comment: @OsbourneRuddock "I don't suppose extensions can selectively enable or disable permissions via user-modifiable extension settings." - yes they can, via the [`chrome.permissions`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions) API.

Answer (score 2):

One way to solve the problem is to use the [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest) API to declaratively register a webRequest listener. The disadvantage of this API is that it is only available to Chrome users on the beta and dev channel at the moment, and less flexible than the webRequest API (the rules are declarative, so you cannot make runtime decisions about request handling that are not supported by the DWR API).

Another way to work around the problem is to use [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to find tabs that had been opened before the extension was launched.

Comment: Any plans / existing crbug issue to take this to Stable?

Comment: Not immediately, because no-one is actively working on it: https://crbug.com/112155

Comment: Thanks, starred to keep an eye on it.

Comment: @Xan You might also be interested in https://crbug.com/447270, an (accepted) proposal to allow event pages to be used with the webRequest API.

Comment: I will hope that the declarativeWebRequest API makes it to Stable.  In the meantime, chrome.tabs.query will not work for me, because I need to block the request.  Thanks for the suggestions!  I will go ahead and give DWR a try so I can be ready for it when it (hopefully) comes.

Comment: In case anyone's wondering, 2.5 years later, `chrome.declarativeWebRequest` is still not in stable.

Comment: @jdunning They are actively working on a replacement - "declarative net request" - https://crbug.com/696822

Comment: Interesting.  Looks like more discussion on the API here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/extensions-reviews/WoKXzxCcXIQ